# Modify array based on conditions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an input array and I am trying to get to an array based on a couple of conditions:

1. For a particular id having both 'O' & 'C' description:
   a). consider only the object with description 'C' if it is a 'AP' code.
   b). If description: 'C' is having a code of 'NA', then consider the object with description: 'O'(at this
   point, this 'O' must be in 'AP')
2. For a particular id with only description as 'O' or only 'C' consider that object only irrespective of the code (NA or AP)

arr1 =

```
[
        {
            "id": 32285,
            "r_id": 38553,
            "code": "NA",
            "description": "C"
        },
        {
            "id": 1235,
            "r_id": 343,
            "code": "NA",
            "description": "C"
        },
        {
            "id": 32285,
            "r_id": 37553,
            "code": "AP",
            "description": "O"
        }
    ]
```

expected result ->

```
 [
        {
            "id": 32285,
            "r_id": 37553,
            "code": "AP",
            "description": "O"
        },
        {
            "id": 1235,
            "r_id": 343,
            "code": "NA",
            "description": "C"
        }
    ]
```

Code that I have(partially works):

```
results = arr1.reduce((a, c, i, t) => {
  if (c.code === 'AP') {
    if (c.description === 'O') {
      a.push({ ...c });
    }
   else if (!t.some((x) => x.id === c.id && x.description === 'C')) {
     a.push({ ...c });
  }
}
 return a;
}, []);
```

Another test case #2

```
arr1 = [
        {
            "inv_id": 32285,
            "resume_id": 38553,
            "subject": "Seat Belt Webbing Failure",
            "status_cd": "APPR",
            "status_description": "CLOSED"
        },
        {
            "inv_id": 32285,
            "resume_id": 37553,
            "subject": "Seat Belt Webbing Failure",
            "status_cd": "APPR",
            "status_description": "OPEN"
        }
    ]
```

expected result ->

```
    [{
        "inv_id": 32285,
        "resume_id": 38553,
        "subject": "Seat Belt Webbing Failure",
        "status_cd": "APPR",
        "status_description": "CLOSED"
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

I might not understand the actual requirement. But I tried to resolve what I understood. Hope it may help. Thank you.

```js
const testArr = [
        {
            "id": 32285,
            "r_id": 38553,
            "code": "NA",
            "description": "C"
        },
        {
            "id": 1235,
            "r_id": 343,
            "code": "NA",
            "description": "C"
        },
        {
            "id": 32285,
            "r_id": 37553,
            "code": "AP",
            "description": "O"
        }
    ]
    
const getArr = (arr) => {
  let temp;
  const sortedArr = arr.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
  
  const finalArr = sortedArr.filter((item, index) => {
    if(!!temp && temp.id === item.id) {
      return ["C", "O"].includes(item.description) && item.code !== "NA";
    } else {
      temp = item;
      
      if(item.id === sortedArr[index + 1]?.id) {
        return ["C", "O"].includes(item.description) && item.code !== "NA";
      }
    }
    
    return ["C", "O"].includes(item.description);
  })
  
  return finalArr;
}

console.log(getArr(testArr));
```